# Storing 5000+ records in Redis cache

Tags: asp.net, redis, asp.net-core-mvc, stackexchange.redis

Hi am new to redis cache, i was looking way to store 5000+ or more  records into redis cache, which should be kind of scalable what would be the easiest way to handle it so that my application doesn't have any performance impact.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64382757/using-map-to-cache-for-around-5000-entries-in-javascript-apllication-vs-redis/64382906#64382906

Answer (score 0):

Before you get more concrete answer you need to give some more about details about the data you want to store there and they way you will get from database.

In general you can check this answer for storing large amount of data in Redis: [Data preparation to upload into Redis server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013343/data-preparation-to-upload-into-redis-server/43021111#43021111)

Comment: am going to store tightly coupled object, kind of class object which is having properties as another classes

Comment: and you will get only this object e.g. 1 record or couple of objects ?

Comment: same class object i need to store, lets say 5000 times to cache with multiple changes in the object data, each time while storing with new change i need to save it as new object

Comment: sorry but your requirement is not clear to me. If you can update your requirements with more complete example in the original post it will be helpful.