# using map to cache for around 5000 entries in Javascript apllication VS Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, redis, maps

I have a **PRICE_MAPPER table** at my DB

It has around **5000 entries**

Price is determined on 3 entry types

A B C ---> 300 (col1:A , col2:B , col3:C , colPrice:300)

X Y Z ---> 500

.. and around *5000 of such entries* (3 unique combinations determining a price)

Planning to put these in a MAP at my Nodejs application

**Concern**: I need advice, putting such a heavy data at my Nodejs application, would that be good decision or bad, as Nodejs is not for memory intensive tasks.

I can cache this data at **REDIS**, but I want to avoid the network call involved in communication with Redis sever, for aiming lowest latency

Comment: rest assured 5000 entries isn't heavy data

Comment: No problem at all putting 5000 entries into a Map object.  That's nothing.

Comment: @jfriend00 Is my assumption correct, where I compare it with Redis

Comment: Assuming your entries are as simple as you describe here, that amounts to pennies storage wise, even across 5,000 entries.

Comment: What assumption?  Yes, Redis would be slower to access than a Map object in node.js.  But, not that much slower because Redis is also keeping the data in memory.  If you have the memory and want to maximize the performance and don't need multi-process access to the data, and don't need any other specific Redis features that a Map object doesn't have, then keep it in nodejs.  Not much else to say.

Comment: @zcoop98 They are simple, just that it would be some strings , instead of sample data, concerned about so many strings in memory !!!

Comment: Strings in memory are no big deal unless you have a very memory constrained nodejs hosting instance.  But, those same strings would be in memory in Redis too. 
 It sounds like you don't want to believe the people that are answering your question.  Or you can take 15 minutes and implement keeping the data in a Map object and just measure whatever you want to measure to see if its working to your liking.  Not sure what else we can say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to have **one single instance** in your node.js application use *internal memory* to store your data.

However, be sure that if the process goes down, you have to put that data back to memory!

Using REDIS could be *a good* solution if you think that you **will have multiple** instances to read the same shared map from the memory and if **there are simultaneous changes** on that map.